# passing '&' in a string from xcode to php?

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, xcode

I am programming with webservice in iphone which access mysql database which contains values like "Mobile&gaming solutions". I'm getting this value in a string from user and passing to php file. But the php is not accepting the string with '&'. It accepts only "Mobile". Help Me. My code in xcode is:

```
strEditbuunit = [labeditbunit.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];

NSString *Updpost =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"buname=%@",strEditbuunit];

UpdLTRhostStr = @"http://localhost/practice/ltrupdate.php?";

UpdLTRhostStr = [UpdLTRhostStr stringByAppendingString:Updpost];  
UpdLTRdataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UpdLTRhostStr]];
UpdLTRserverOutput = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:UpdLTRdataURL encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];


<?php
$con = mysql_connect("192.168.0.82","android","android");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db("androidlogin", $con);
$buname = $_GET["buname"];
$retval1 = mysql_query( "SELECT code_id FROM typedescs where name = '$buname'" );
    while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($retval1))
    {
        $bu_id = $row1['code_id'];

    }
 echo $buname;
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

When I echo buname it gives me "Mobile" instead of "Mobile&Gaming solutions" because of '&'. Please help me how to pass the string with special characters to php from xcode.

Comment: Nice [SQL injection hole](http://bobby-tables.com). Enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with PHP.  You are not quoting the query parameters in your URL.

```
UpdLTRhostStr = @"http://localhost/practice/ltrupdate.php?";
UpdLTRhostStr = [UpdLTRhostStr stringByAppendingString:Updpost];
```

Here's one way to do it:

```
UpdLTRhostStr = [NSString
    stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost/practice/ltrupdate.php?buname=%@",
    CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
        kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef) buunit, NULL,
        CFSTR(":/?#[]@!$&’()*+,;="), kCFStringEncodingUTF8)];
```

Don't forget that you need to escape the string on the PHP side, too, before you pass it to MySQL.  As Marc B pointed out, you have a serious security hole.

Comment: how to do that.give me some example pls.

Comment: @user2210195: For example, if you have `&`, it gets replaced with `%26`.  Other special characters get replaced in the same fashion.

Comment: I used $buname = mysql_escape_string($_GET["buname"]); in php side.Is it right.It doesn't work.Im new to php also.plz help

Comment: "It doesn't work" isn't specific enough.  You  need to tell us what actually happened, and what you expected to happen.